# Filtering option in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, d3.js, rickshaw

I am working on D3(Rickshaw framework) where I have to filter the data using the name.

Here is the code which rickshaw uses for creating the circle.

```
var nodes = graph.vis.selectAll("path").data(series.stack.filter(function(d) {
    return d.y !== null
})).enter().append("svg:circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
    return graph.x(d.x)
}).attr("cy", function(d) {
    return graph.y(d.y)
}).attr("fill-opacity", 1.0).attr('transform', 'translate(22,0)').attr("r", function(d) {
    return ("r" in d) ? d.r : graph.renderer.dotSize
});
```

I tried to filter the data like

```
$('#BestBrands input').on("change", function () {   
    console.log("called")
    var selected = $(this).attr('name'),
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
    console.log(selected)

    graph.vis.selectAll(".filter")
        .data(series.stack.filter(function(d) {
            return series.name[0] == selected
        }))    
        .attr("display", display);
});
```

//series.name is equal to d.name in d3.js so series[0] is first co-ordinates name
It`s not working. Do I need to append any class in the class? I am not clear with this. What should I do here to filter the data according to the name?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your code :

```
graph.vis.selectAll("path")
  .data(series.stack.filter(function(d){
        //should return a boolean
        return selected === 'something';
       }))
    .attr("display", display);
});
```

EDIT :

```
$('#BestBrands input').on("change", function () {   
    console.log("called")
    var selected = $(this).attr('name'),
        display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
    console.log(selected)

    graph.vis.selectAll(".filter")
        .data(series.stack.filter(function(d) {
            return series[0].name == selected //assuming series[] is an array
        }))    
        .attr("display", display);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you intend to use `var selected = $(this).attr('name')` but never compare it to anything.

In this line:

```
series.stack.filter(function(d){ return d.selected })
```

I suspect you want to compare `d.selected` to `selected`. Now, this is just me assuming (and you know what they say about assuming), but given my experience with D3, `series.stack.filter` will iterate over the elements in `series.stack`, so you'll need to make sure that `d.selected` is the property that you want.